# Are IBM PowerPC CPUs free of the AMT issue seen with AMD and Intel?

Tags: hardware, backdoor, ibm

Given the [privacy and security risks associated with Intel's Management Engine and AMD's Platform Security Processor](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128619/what-are-the-privacy-and-security-risks-associated-with-intels-management-engin), are IBM PowerPC processors such as the [POWER9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POWER9) susceptible to similar hardware-level attacks?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question. Whether or not a piece of hardware has a capability is not about security. The *implications* of the feature can be a security question (just like the question you linked).

Comment: @schroeder Thanks for the feedback, I have updated, hopefully this question is more relevant now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Power9 does not have a function similar to the Intel ME and AMD PSP built in to the processor.  (Or, at least, no such function is documented.)  It was even chosen as the [processor of choice for a security-focused platform](https://raptorcs.com/TALOSII/).

Comment: Can you provide any more info / links which support this?